# Dynamic ListView breaking after scrolling

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I have a list that is dynamic. I used [this tutorial](http://custom-listview-with-separate-headers.blogspot.com/). It is all loading correctly, but when I scroll, my headers go out of wack and out of order. My code is slightly different from the tutorial; a text on left right, and center instead of image and two text views. The list view is populated from Parse.com.

This is my log cat.

```
 09-26 20:51:27.115      757-757/com.codealchemist.clashmma E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
    at com.codealchemist.clashmma.SeparatedListAdapter.getView(SeparatedListAdapter.java:105)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2143)
    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:708)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:647)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4930)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3087)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3361)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7246)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2168)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1903)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1953)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1405)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2410)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1901)
    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7426)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4271)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:4342)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4382)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:530)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:379)
    ... 48 more
```

The LogCat is saying I have an error here in my `SeparatedListAdapter.java`

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return (getItemViewType(position) != TYPE_SECTION_HEADER);
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    int sectionnum = 0;
    for (Object section : this.sections.keySet())
    {
        Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);
        int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;

        // check if position inside this section
 <----//This is (SeparatedListAdapter.java:105) ----->
        if (position == 0) return headers.getView(sectionnum, convertView, parent);
        if (position < size) return adapter.getView(position - 1, convertView, parent);

        // otherwise jump into next section
        position -= size;
        sectionnum++;
    }
    return null;
}
```

The tutorial I followed didn't give much explanation to this and what it really does. So how do I fix this to display properly before and after scrolling?

**EDIT**

Where I populate my adapter

```
      @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_list);

    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(fightCard.this, "", "Loading bout...", true);
    progressDialog.show();

    // Used this tutorial      http://custom-listview-with-separate-headers.blogspot.in/


    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Listview);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            HomeItem homeItem = (HomeItem) adapter.getItem(position);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), homeItem.getHomeItemLeft().toString() + " " + homeItem.getHomeItemRight().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.println("Selected Item : " + homeItem.getHomeItemID());

        }
    });

    PopulateHomePageItemList();
}

private void PopulateHomePageItemList() {
    adapter = new SeparatedListAdapter(this);


    //create the main event
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> MainEventQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("MainEvent");
    MainEventQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> parseObjects, ParseException e) {
            if(e == null){
                int i = 0;
                int size = parseObjects.size();
                Log.d("MAIN EVENT SIZE", size + "");
                HomeItemList = new ArrayList<HomeItem>();
                while (i < size){
                    HomeItem homeItem = new HomeItem();
                    homeItem.setHomeItemID(i);
                    name1 = parseObjects.get(i).getString("red");
                    homeItem.setHomeItemLeft(name1);
                    name2 = parseObjects.get(i).getString("blue");
                    homeItem.setHomeItemRight(name2);
                    HomeItemList.add(homeItem);
                    i++;
                }

                HomeListAdapter = new  HomeListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 0, HomeItemList);
                if(HomeListAdapter!= null)
                    adapter.addSection(" MAIN EVENT ", HomeListAdapter );

            }
        }
    });



    //create the co-main event

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> CoMain = ParseQuery.getQuery("CoMainEvent");
    CoMain.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> parseObjects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null){
                int i = 0;
                int size = parseObjects.size();
                Log.d("Co-MAIN SIZE", size + "");
                HomeItemList = new ArrayList<HomeItem>();
                while (i < size){
                    HomeItem homeItem = new HomeItem();
                    homeItem.setHomeItemID(i);
                    name1 = parseObjects.get(i).getString("red");
                    homeItem.setHomeItemLeft(name1);
                    name2 = parseObjects.get(i).getString("blue");
                    homeItem.setHomeItemRight(name2);
                    HomeItemList.add(homeItem);
                    i++;
                }
                HomeListAdapter = new  HomeListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 0, HomeItemList);
                if(HomeListAdapter!= null)
                    adapter.addSection(" CO-MAIN EVENT ", HomeListAdapter );

            }
        }
    });

    //create the fight card
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> bout = ParseQuery.getQuery("bout");
    bout.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> parseObjects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null){
                int i = 0;
                int size = parseObjects.size();
                Log.d("BOUT SIZE", size + "");
                HomeItemList = new ArrayList<HomeItem>();
                while (i < size) {
                    HomeItem homeItem = new HomeItem();
                    homeItem.setHomeItemID(i);
                    name1 = parseObjects.get(i).getString("red");
                    homeItem.setHomeItemLeft(name1);
                    name2 = parseObjects.get(i).getString("blue");
                    homeItem.setHomeItemRight(name2);
                    HomeItemList.add(homeItem);
                    i++;
                }
                HomeListAdapter = new  HomeListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 0, HomeItemList);
                if(HomeListAdapter!= null)
                    adapter.addSection(" FIGHT CARD ", HomeListAdapter );


            }
        }
    });
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    progressDialog.dismiss();

}

 }
```

Comment: Post the code where you use (populate) your adapter.

Comment: FYI, you might be interested in the [StickyListHeaders](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders) project code as well, if this one doesn't work out for you...

Comment: I tried the StickyListHeaders, I liked it, but it did more than what I needed. I did like it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logcat stacktrace indicates that a `LinearLayout` is trying to be cast as a `TextView`. Have you addressed this error already?

Comment: No I have not... I'm not sure how I am doing this or how to fix it

Comment: What is on: SeparatedListAdapter.java:105

Comment: Ah.. You're using Parse.com.. all of those calls to "findInBackground" will return at (possibly) different times, so your calls of "adapter.addSection()" may come back and execute out-of-order.. Who knows when they each return, since this is done asynchronously.

Comment: See my update in my `SeparatedListAdapter.java` the commented line is SeparatedListAdaper.java:105

Comment: Yes, I am, and I know that is an issue, cause it will put my list in the wrong order with headers listed more than once. But is that what is causing my error?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38127/discussion-between-binghammer-and-mistr)

Comment: Ok. From looking at 105, it looks like the code "headers.getView()" when position==0 is returning a LinearLayout, and the code that received this view is expecting it to be a TextView. (or vice-versa). Look in SeparatedListAdapter for where getView() is being used, and it is prob. trying to use a LinearLayout as a TextView.